# How to repair/replace a single faulty table on a MySQL slave server?

Tags: mysql, replication

My [MySQL replication check tool](https://github.com/BenMorel/mysql-replication-check) suddenly started reporting a table with a wrong checksum on the slave, after months of perfect replication.

**Is there a way to instruct the slave to reload the faulty table from the master?**

This table is quite small (2% of the total DB size) so I'd like to avoid setting up replication all over again with a full mysqldump, if possible.

Comment: Look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldbcompare.html Maybe can help you

Comment: Look at `pt-table-cksum` and its companion `pt-table-sync`.  The latter fixes the table.